# Encryption used for Azure App Token in File Share storage

Tags: azure, encryption, single-sign-on, azure-storage, azure-authentication

Is anyone familiar if there is a way to decrypt the encrypted token located in the auto-generated JSON file in `data/.auth/tokens`? (or perhaps replicate the encryption logic)

Here's a sample value generated after Google SSO authentication via Azure's Authentication:

```
{
  "encrypted": true,
  "tokens": {
    "google": "bSkjj928IlEFfMVRKerckUnn7BOAO0md1YHEfeIL3z4zlPrXUzKT65EzVWq3mE5g6I2N8FN5kR7Z8LO/O/jFO7IvcNsX0Ne56GzjYDNrTXg+U9hLri7G7h054hliwM/..."
  },
  "version": 1
}
```

I found this [link](https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/) mentioning that it could be done but didn't provide any detail mentioning how. I am hoping to replicate this storage logic for my custom SSO implementation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

•   The token located in the auto generated JSON file that you are referring to is the JWT token, i.e., JSON web token which is contained in that file. Thus, to decode and decrypt the token, you can go to the following website and check whether the token is valid or not by entering the JWT and hitting ‘decode’ button. That will display all the three parts of the JWT that it consists of, i.e., header, payload, and signature and if you have the passphrase through which you have encoded the signature, then you can use it verify the signature through which token signing during SSO is done.

https://developer.pingidentity.com/en/tools/jwt-decoder.html

[image: JWT token decode]

Also, find the above screenshot depicting a sample JWT token decoded. Similarly, if you want to create a JWT token with a passphrase to pass in one of the session, then you have to create entries according to the header, payload and the signature used and then use it to create one. Thus, the JWT is consisted of as below: -

The three parts are encoded separately using Base64url Encoding RFC 4648, and
concatenated using periods to produce the JWT are: -

```
const token = base64urlEncoding(header) + '.' + base64urlEncoding(payload) + '.' + base64urlEncoding(signature)
```

Please find below links for more information: -

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I don't think that the token inside the JSON is a JWT. I provided a sample content of the JSON file for reference. Thanks!

Comment: It is difficult from the sample posted to identify what type of token it is. It would be helpful if you share some more details as in what type of application are you using, what task are you doing and environment details.

Comment: It's from an Azure Function App Authentication. The sample is auto-generated after a successful call of `.auth/login/google`. For reference for the setup environment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-google. I haven't done any modifications yet besides the basic setup. Thanks!